# Websocket - IOException: Too many open files

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am using Spring boot's WebSocketConfigurer for creating websocket, as per following code to create a presence system. My users would connect to it and it will keep tracking their presence.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketServerConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {

private final PresenceListener presenceListener;
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketServerConfiguration.class.getName());

@Autowired
public WebSocketServerConfiguration(StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate){
    this.presenceListener = new PresenceListener(stringRedisTemplate);
}

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler() {
        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
            logger.info("afterConnectionEstablished:"+session.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
            //Some code inside
        }

        @Override
        public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
            logger.info("handleTransportError:" +session.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
            logger.info("afterConnectionClosed:"+session.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
            return false;
        }
    }, "/presence").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
```

}

After some time after deploying I start getting following Exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(java.base@9-internal/Native Method) ~[na:na]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(java.base@9-internal/ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:424) ~[na:na]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(java.base@9-internal/ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:252) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:443) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-internal/Thread.java:804) [na:na]
```

Please help with this issue.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using (which Tomcat version?) There was a bug with some Tomcat versions: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60035

Comment: 1.5.6 spring boot version and I am not using external tomcat server.

Comment: Then you should be fine as far as the above issue is concerned. Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE embedds Tomcat 8.5.16 which should contain the fix.
Is this error on linux or other OS ?

Comment: I got this exception in logfile when the websocket system was not working. and this happened twice already.

Comment: If it is intermittent, maybe you have too many simultaneous users... Maybe something is leaking the file descriptors... Keep monitoring it while under load. Depending on the platform you are running this on, you could *up* the number of allowed file handlers for your process.

Comment: I don't know where is file descriptor leaking, for this process I only used redis to keep the presence state user.